# How to choose resistance and capacitance value in active bandpass filter?

Tags: active-filter, band-pass

I am trying to make a bandpass filter around 300Hz using this circuit. I have calculated the values of the components using the equations shown in this [website](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_7.html) assuming low frequency cutoff 160Hz and high frequency cutoff 480Hz.

[image: Active Bandpass Filter]

With the equations you get values of RC. So I thought I could select the resistance and capacitance as I wish as long as RC gets the right value.

But when I choose R1=1k, R2=330, C1=C2=1u and simulate it with Proteus the frequency response is nothing like a bandpass filter. 
[image: Non Working]

But when I choose R2=3300 and C2=0.1u frequency response is fine.

[image: Working]

Why does one work and the other does not?

PS: I am using a LM358 operational amplifier.

Answer (score 2):

the equations you are using for calculating the values of the components are established by considering that the OP-AMP is perfect.

Of course it's not the fact and by choosing R2=330 and C2=1uf you have a relative low impedence between the output of your amplifier and the (-) input. The LM358 cannot give enough current for this.

By using R2=3300 and C2=0.1u, the current needed is lower and then the LM358 is close to a perfect OP-AMP.